# Load Bitmap Into ImageView using Glide

Tags: android, bitmap, android-asynctask, android-recyclerview, android-glide

**Background**

I have a `RecyclerView` (with GridLayoutManager) in my app which needs to show some sensitive encrypted images stored locally.

I cannot use something like this,

```
  Glide.with(this).load(encryptedImageFile).into(imageView);
```

as I first need to decrypt them and then set the image.

**What I Have Done**

I have an AsyncTask which decrypts those small thumbnail images and gives me a resulting Bitmap to set in the ImageView.

Here are some small code snippets of the Adapter and the AsyncTask.

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MediaViewHolder holder, int position) {
        super.onBindViewHolder(holder, position);

        EncryptedFileContainer encryptedFileContainer = getItem(position);

        if (encryptedFileContainer != null) {
            EncryptedFileDBModel encryptedFileDBModel = encryptedFileContainer.getEncryptedFileDBModel();
            holder.mImage.setTag(encryptedFileDBModel.getOriginalFileName());

            new BindEncryptedThumbnail(holder, encryptedFileContainer).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
        }
    }
```

The AsyncTask to decrypt and set Bitmaps to the ImageViews,

```
static class BindEncryptedThumbnail extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Bitmap> {
    private EncryptedFileContainer mEncryptedFileContainer;
    private MediaViewHolder mHolder;

    public BindEncryptedThumbnail(MediaViewHolder viewHolder, EncryptedFileContainer encryptedFileContainer) {
        this.mHolder = viewHolder;
        this.mEncryptedFileContainer = encryptedFileContainer;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Object... objects) {
        if (mEncryptedFileContainer.getEncryptedFile() != null) {
            return mEncryptedFileContainer.getDecryptedThumb().getThumb(100);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap thumbnail) {
        String name = (String) mHolder.mImage.getTag();
        EncryptedFile encryptedFile = mEncryptedFileContainer.getEncryptedFile();
        EncryptedFileDBModel encryptedFileDBModel = mEncryptedFileContainer.getEncryptedFileDBModel();
        if (encryptedFile != null && StringUtils.equals(name, encryptedFileDBModel.getOriginalFileName())
                && (thumbnail != null) && (mHolder.mImage != null)) {
            mHolder.mImage.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
        } else {
            mHolder.mImage.setImageDrawable(ResourceUtils.getDrawable(R.drawable.img_placeholder));
        }
    }
}
```

**The Problem**

Everything works fine and images are decrypted properly and being set in the RecyclerView items correctly. But **when there are lots of images the memory footprint of the app shoots high up and there are several GCs** as there is no BitmapPool to efficiently load images.

I would not like to implement disk caching and BitmapPool by myself as these have been effectively done in Glide (*FYI, I am using Glide in other parts of my app*).

**I would like to use Glide to load a Bitmap (returned by my AsyncTask) and set it into the ImageView** so that I can decrypt my images and also make use of all the goodness Glide offers.

**EDIT**:

Adding more information on how I am generating the thumbnail.

```
public Bitmap getThumb(int thumbnailSize) {
        if ((!mThumbnailCreated) && (mThumbnailBitmap == null)) {
            CipherInputStream streamThumb = readStream();
            this.mThumbnailBitmap = ThumbnailEncryptionFactory
                    .getThumbnailfromStream(streamThumb, thumbnailSize);
        }
        return mThumbnailBitmap;
    }
```

and this,

```
public static Bitmap getThumbnailfromStream(CipherInputStream streamThumb, int size) {
        if (streamThumb != null) {
            try {
                byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(streamThumb);
                return decodeSampledBitmapFromByte(bytes, size, size);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Timber.d("Error decoding thumbnail.");
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromByte(byte[] stream, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(stream, 0, stream.length, options);

        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(stream, 0, stream.length, options);
    }
```

Comment: The solution involves setting up a custom `ResourceDecoder` and specifying its use i.e. `Glide.with(this).load(encryptedImageFile).decoder(myDecoder).into(imageView);` I will work on the answer later when I have time.  I'm going to assume you can get an `InputStream` containing the decrypted but not-yet-PNG-decoded bytes for the image.  I'm also going to assume that your decryption is thread-safe.

Comment: @krislarson Thanks for the insight. I have updated the question with details on how I am generating the thumbnail. So, yes I will be having a CipherInputStream of the encrypted thumbnail ready. And I haven't done anything about thread-safety yet, any insight into that would be helpful. If you need any more info about the problem, please let me know.

Comment: Crosslink: https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/1498

Comment: Well.  Looks like somebody beat me to it. :)